# How to use JAXB for generating getters with lazy initialization

Tags: jaxb, jax-ws, getter

I try to get beans generated with JAXB, where the getter-Methods have a implicit initialization (lazy initialization) like in the following example.

```
public test.Address getAddress()
{
    if (_address==null)
    {
        setAddress(new test.Address());
    }
    return _address;
}
```

Is this possible at all?